# Variance of the empirical mean

Tags: statistics, expected-value, means

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be i.i.d. R.V. with variance $\sigma^2$
Is the $$\text{Var}{\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n}}=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$$ **or rather**
$$\text{Var}{\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n}}=\frac{\sigma^2}{n-1}$$ ?

I just remember that sometimes $n$ is decreased to $n-1$ by loosing one degree of freedom when computing moment's, is this that case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the first. When you compute the variance you get with $\bar{X}_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ that
$$
var[\bar{X}_n] = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n var[X_i] = \frac{n}{n^2} var[X_1] = \frac{\sigma^2}{n},
$$
where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of the $X_i$.
The reduced $n-1$ in the denominator usually comes into play when *estimating* the variance of the $X_i$. In this case
$$
\widehat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar{X}_n)^2
$$
is an unbiased estimator for $\sigma^2$, i.e., $\mathbb{E}[\widehat{\sigma}^2] = \sigma^2$.
Another place where $n-1$ can be found is in the construction of confidence intervals for the mean when using a t-statistic.

Comment: How did you derive this $\mathbb{E}[\widehat{var}] = \sigma^2$ : did you really mean $\mathbb{E}[\widehat{var}] = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ **or even** $\mathbb{E}[\widehat{var}] = \frac{\sigma^2}{n-1}$ ?

Comment: Here $\widehat{\sigma}^2$ (which I denoted by $\widehat{var}$ before the edit) is the variance of the $X_i$, not of the empirical mean - I edited the post to make that more clear. You can find a proof here: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/4744/prove-the-sample-variance-is-an-unbiased-estimator/4759